# What is wrong with this SQL query

Tags: mysql

What's wrong with this SQL query .. it keeps giving me an error .. and the error is also noted below

here's the query :

```
    UPDATE Politicians SET Big Fan = Big Fan +3 WHERE ID = '2' 
 MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
```

Comment: What is the datatype of Big fan?

Comment: space is column name?

Comment: Provide the output of `show columns from Politicians`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE Politicians SET `Big Fan` = `Big Fan` +3 WHERE ID = '2'
```

Use backticks if the column name has a space.

Answer (score 0):

the space between Big and Fan. What is that "big fan" !?

Answer (score 0):

If the datatype of `Big Fan` is `int` then you just want to change like this:

```
UPDATE Politicians SET `Big Fan` = `Big Fan` +3 WHERE ID = '2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your column name has a space, use it like this:

```
UPDATE Politicians SET `Big Fan` = `Big Fan` +3 
WHERE ID = '2'
```

Answer (score 0):

First check that the column name **Big Fan** exists in database with a space between them. If yes then you have to enclose these type of attributes within backtick symbol Like:

```
`Big Fan`
```

So your query will become:

```
UPDATE Politicians SET `Big Fan` = `Big Fan` + 3 WHERE ID = '2'
```